# #Dart : how can I split string from integer ex: (u2345678) needs to store u as string and numbers as integer

Tags: dart

Dart : how can I split string from integer ex: (u2384567) needs to store u as string and numbers as integer

x=u2384567

expecting :
string y= u;
z= 2384567;

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to split String with specific pattern.

```
  String str = 'btc24546646';
  RegExp intSplit = RegExp('[0-9]');
  RegExp stringSplit = RegExp('[a-z]');
 
  final String y = str.replaceAll(intSplit, '');
  final String z = str.replaceAll(stringSplit, '');

  print(y);
  print(z);
```